# UWP Enumerate Folders with 10,000 files while creating a subfolder

Tags: c#, vb.net, uwp, enumerate, storagefile

I'm a fairly experienced developer, but this has me stumped in UWP - I'll keep it simple.

Let's say I want to go through all photos in the pictures folder, watermark them, and save the watermarked version in a sub folder of pictures (eg. pictures\watermarked)

Sound easy?

**Try 1:** Using GetFilesAsync (incl. GetItemsAsync, GetFoldersAsync) - This method goes through every file, giving me the StorageFile objects I need.

There are 2 problems with this approach:

1. I can't show a progress bar until I've scanned every file and that's
   painfully slow in UWP.
2. The Runtime Broker will consume all memory if I keep any reference
   to the StorageFile object (so enumerate and enumerate again to get a
   progress is seriously slow, think 1,000 times slower than Win32)

**Try 2:** Using Queries - This method involves using Windows.System.Search & Queries to return a list of pointers (ish) to all the files. I can then use StorageFolderQueryResult to get each StorageFile on the fly and release immediately so that the Runtime Broker behaves. This is very fast as it uses the  Windows Index system, really, really fast.

The problem is that the query system is fairly stupid, as soon I create the subfolder "Watermarked Photos", the storagefiles returned by the Query (which did not exist when it was queried) start to contain files from the Watermarked folder. It appears that the Query is actually just a number of files, not a static list of the actual files, so the results are arbitrary based on any files added/removed after the query was invoked within it's scope.

Anyone with thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Get time when you start a query and then search files that changed before start time.  Still not 100% but a little better.

Comment: Thanks, that can be achieved through the Changed Event as well as time, however, to scan 10,000 files to see which ones are new would take a long time, even on an SSD that could take 10 minutes :(

Comment: is it as simple as writing the initial query results to a local list object, then enumerating through that instead of the query directly?

Comment: Unfortunately, storing the results means the Windows Runtime Broker will kill the system, consume all memory, and bring windows to a grinding halt.

Comment: "I can't show a progress bar " could I know what does this mean? What's the progress bar control used for? "if I keep any reference to the StorageFile" did you reference the 10000 at the same time? How you monitor the memory costing?

Comment: try using this method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.search.storagefilequeryresult#Windows_Storage_Search_StorageFileQueryResult_GetFilesAsync_System_UInt32_System_UInt32_    You could convert say 10 pictures at a time, and then dispose of any references and take the next 10 pictures. This way you can even implement a progress bar fairly easy.

Comment: Hi. So the progress bar is just a progress to the user as I process the files. If I try and load all storagefiles into an array/list and then process them the runtime broker kills windows. My app uses almost nothing memory wise, but task manager shows the broker consuming all memory. It’s know by Microsoft that it does this.

Comment: The article to load 10 pictures at a time does not circumnavigate the issue that the query will return the wrong files once any subfolder changes. So as soon as my app adds a file to be sub folder, query index results are wrong.

Comment: So that the reason "I can't show a progress bar" is because "the runtime broker kills windows"?  For "painfully slow ", could I know  `GetFilesAsync ` slow or watermarked one by one slow?  Actually I need to comprehending what the problem  you have with `GetFilesAsync`. Could you please detail  executing which code line the Runtime Broker will consume all memory ? Could you please use the vs performance tool to monitor your project to narrow the issue? Or provide some code snippet or screenshot to help detail your issue.

Comment: Consider using QueryOptions `QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions();
queryOptions.FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Shallow;` to prevent the edited pictures from your subfolder to be returned as results.

Comment: So here’s the problem with GetFilesAsync. Var Files = await Folder.GetFilesAsync(aLargeFolder). If the folder has 10,000 files, the windows Runtime Broker starts to eat through memory and dies before returning the results. In tests I found that 29,000 will cause windows to die. It’s the runtime broker that causes it. Yes 29,000 files is a lot, but when working with photo archives I commonly see over 100,000 files. Not all in one folder (hence you need to enumerate first to see how many and therefore be able to show the user a progress). Win32 can do this with almost no memory overhead.

Comment: queryOptions.FolderDepth Is a good option to prevent deep scanning, but deep scanning is needed to get all the sub folders. I could run multiple shallow queries, but the more queries you run, let’s say 400, windows will die. Again, you can’t store 400 shallow queries in memory, you can’t store more than a few thousand storage object of any kind.

Comment: maybe you can use query options to sort the pictures by date, so the edited one will show up last, and you can stop once you get pictures with a certain creation time. However since that would require all files to be sorted by the system i assume that wont work either. But maybe its worth a try.

Comment: @Hannes. Unfortunately that wouldn’t work as UWP set the the created date after 2 seconds, not at the time of writing the file. Also, as the query returns a number of files based on the initial scan, while I could use the date to exclude the edited ones, the newly added files means that the query ‘count’ of files will end before all the files are read. Eg. Query says  10,000 files, by the time I’m half way through there are now 15,000 files. The query will only give me access to 10k files, so maybe 5k original and then 5k the edited, I lose 5k of files

Comment: Im not sure what you mean with set the the created date after 2 seconds. (Is the date set 2 sec after you save the file) The query, even if it might give you only 10K items it should give you the old (unedited) items first, so why should there be maybe 5k of the other ones in there? A (admittedly pretty dirty) workaround would be to put the edited picture in a folder outside the picture folder and move them back there after completion (maybe even by hand via the file explorer)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. To answer each point, if you save a file and set the creation date, windows will overwrite it 2 seconds later with its date. Only an issue if I set it, which I do.  Now looking at the query, it doesn’t return the original files first. It simply counts/sorts, but when you ask for a file, it returns a file based on the current state of the folders/files, not the original state, so if anything has changed, you get unexpected results. The last option to move the folder somewhere else is an option but forced a user experience due to technical limits, that’s always bad.

Comment: Write a self answer, instead of adding solved or stuff like that to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED - It's not possible using the index system. I created my own Query class. It uses the GetItemsAsync method of folders, the number of objects here won't kill the RuntimeBroker, I store the Path in a string list. containing the paths of all files and sub folders. I can then use GetFileFromPathAsync to instantiate and destroy StorageItems as needed. The RuntimeBroker is okay with that, although it's not the best performance it does give me custom file/folder filtering. Happy to elaborate if anyone needs more info.